# Leave only rows where first column is same in both files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have two .csv files where the first column is some name and other columns describe that name. I want to process those files in a way where in the second file I leave only rows where first column is the same in both files. Also duplicates should be removed for further processing. Data in columns other than column zero can be different in both files.

test1.csv

```
cat,house,guest
dog,environment
mouse,broom
mouse,broom
```

test2.csv

```
cat,house,boy
dog,environment
mouse,broom,hole
path,leave
cat,house,boy
```

What I want to receive:

1_processed.csv

```
cat,house,guest
dog,environment
mouse,broom
```

2_processed.csv

```
cat,house,boy
dog,environment
mouse,broom,hole
```

I tried following code with pandas to achieve it, however it does not work as expected:

```
import pandas as pd

file1 = "test1.csv"
file2 = "test2.csv"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Getting columns from file")
    df1 = pd.read_csv(file1, header=None, sep="delimiter", engine="python")

    print("Getting columns from file")
    df2 = pd.read_csv(file2, header=None, sep="delimiter", engine="python")

    print("Leave only rows where first column is same in both files")
    df2.drop(df2[~df2[0].isin(df1[0])], inplace=True)

    print("Remove duplicated rows")
    df1.drop_duplicates(subset=None, inplace=True)
    df2.drop_duplicates(subset=None, inplace=True)

    print("Write processed data to files")
    df1.to_csv("1_processed", index=False, header=False)
    df2.to_csv("2_processed", index=False, header=False)
```

Output:

1_processed.csv

```
"cat,house,guest"
"dog,environment"
"mouse,broom"
```

2_processed.csv

```
"dog,environment"
"mouse,broom,hole"
"path,leave"  #this value should not appear here
"cat,house,boy"
```

Comment: Aside from the inconsistencies like `sep="delimiter"` that should be `sep=","` or removed and the missing same command `df2.drop(df2[~df2[0].isin(df1[0])], inplace=True)` for `df1`, what doesn't work?

Comment: I edited the question, added my output. There is a row in processed file which should not be there and it causes chaos for file with multiple lines and various data. I tried adding same command for df1 but results were even worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [**`pandas.DataFrame.eq`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) :

```
import pandas as pd

file1 = "test1.csv"
file2 = "test2.csv"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Getting columns from file1")
    df1 = pd.read_csv(file1, header=None)

    print("Getting columns from file2")
    df2 = pd.read_csv(file2, header=None)

    print("Remove duplicated rows")
    df1 = df1.drop_duplicates()
    df2 = df2.drop_duplicates()

    print("Leave only rows where first column is same in both files")
    df2 = df2[df1.eq(df2)[0]]

    print("Write processed data to files")
    df1.to_csv("1_processed.csv", index=False, header=False)
    df2.to_csv("2_processed.csv", index=False, header=False)
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df1)  

       0            1      2
0    cat        house  guest
1    dog  environment    NaN
2  mouse        broom    NaN

print(df2)

       0            1     2
0    cat        house   boy
1    dog  environment   NaN
2  mouse        broom  hole
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It does work for the test dataset but it still failed for my target one. I eventually gave up using pandas, it's simpler to just use raw file functions